# Transferrring files to san disk secure access software using batch files

Tags: batch-file

I am using sandisk usb and it has inbuilt software called secure access software with vault access,I have created a folder in it and want to transfer all the data  on to that folder, this is my script when I run this it detects the USb drive creates a folder and copies them into that folder instead of the secure folder .

[image]

[image]
.
this is my script

```
@echo off
    setLocal Enabledelayedexpansion

    set "myDrive="

    for %%a in (a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z) do (
        if not defined myDrive vol %%a: >nul 2>nul && ( 
            if exist "%%a:\RunSanDiskSecureAccess_Win.exe" set "myDrive=%%a:"
        )
    )

    if defined myDrive (
        echo drive found [%myDrive%]
    ) else (
        echo USB drive has not been found
) 

ping 10.10.10.10 -n 1 -w 5000 > nul
xcopy "E:\Export\*.*" "%myDrive%\My Vault\transit\" /e /i /y
xcopy E:\Export\*.*  E:\Backup\

echo msgbox"All Files Transferred Successfully">a.vbs&a.vbs&del a.vbs
exit
```